# How to cross compile application for 32 bit arm architecture on amd64 system using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, arm, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am new to arm-linuxgnueabihf-g++. I am working on an amd64 machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and having arm-linuxgnueabihf-g++-4.7 installed. I want to cross-compile my application targeting 32-bit arm architecture.

I run command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -m32 hello.cpp -o hello.
```

But it gave me the error: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error:

```
unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’.
```

And seems there is little documentation about arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ on the Internet.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you've been using google search wrong. If I apply [gcc "-m32"](https://www.google.de/search?q=gcc+-m32&rlz=1Y3KTZR_deDE555DE555&oq=gcc+-m32&aqs=chrome..69i57.14804j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=gcc+%22-m32%22) I get plenty of results that might help you out.

Answer (score 6):

`-m32` is an x86 option. It is not supported (or needed) on ARM, where different toolchains are used for 32-bit and 64-bit code.

The 64-bit ARM (AArch64) toolchain is called aarch64-linux-gnu.

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to compile my code targeting the 32-bit ARM on amd64 machine, what toolchain should I use?

Comment: The one you have, just drop the '-m32'.